Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Poisson Mean with Given Observations
You have a sample of $n$ i.i.d. realizations of the random variable $X$ distributed as a Poisson with parameter $\lambda$. It is known that:

$n_1$ values are greater than or equal to $2$;
$n_2$ values are equal to $1$;
The remaining observations are equal to $0$.

a. Determine the maximum likelihood estimator for the mean of the Poisson distribution.
Solution:
The Poisson distribution is defined by the probability mass function:
$$ P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!} $$
The probabilities for each category are:

Probability of observing $X = 0$:
$$ P(X = 0) = e^{-\lambda} $$

Probability of observing $ X = 1 $:
$$ P(X = 1) = \lambda e^{-\lambda} $$

Probability of observing $ ( X \geq 2 ): $
$$ P(X \geq 2) = 1 - P(X = 0) - P(X = 1) = 1 - e^{-\lambda} - \lambda e^{-\lambda} $$


Given $ n_1 $ values are greater than or equal to $ 2 $, $ n_2 $ values are $ 1 $, and the rest are $ 0 $, the likelihood function is:
$$ L(\lambda) = (e^{-\lambda})^{n - n_1 - n_2} (\lambda e^{-\lambda})^{n_2} \left(1 - e^{-\lambda} - \lambda e^{-\lambda}\right)^{n_1} $$
The log-likelihood function $\ell(\lambda) $ simplifies to:
$$ \ell(\lambda) = -(n - n_1 - n_2)\lambda + n_2 (\log \lambda - \lambda) + n_1 \log\left(1 - e^{-\lambda} - \lambda e^{-\lambda}\right) $$
To find the maximum likelihood estimator, differentiate $\ell(\lambda) $ with respect to $ \lambda $ and set the derivative equal to zero:
$$ \frac{d\ell(\lambda)}{d\lambda} = -(n - n_1 - n_2) + \frac{n_2}{\lambda} - n_2 + n_1 \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda}}{1 - e^{-\lambda} - \lambda e^{-\lambda}} $$
Calculating the final step is challenging (assuming the preceding steps are correct), and I am uncertain how to resolve this exercise

Do you have a specific ${n}, {n}{1}, {n}{2}$?

@Royi The question in the text referred to finding the estimator, not the estimate. At this point, I believe the text is "incorrect" because the other questions are also related to the definition of the estimator in general

The estimator cannot be found explicitly, but can be proven to exist.

The critical point $\hat \lambda$ satisfies
$$n - n_1 = \frac{n_2}{\lambda} + \frac{n_1 \lambda}{e^\lambda - (1 + \lambda)}$$
or equivalently,
$$e^\lambda = \frac{n_2 - (n - n_1 - n_2)\lambda - n \lambda^2}{n_2 - (n - n_1)\lambda}. \tag{1}$$
For most permissible choices of $n, n_1, n_2$ and a suitably large initial guess $\lambda_0$, the recursion $$\lambda_{m+1} = \log \frac{n_2 - (n - n_1 - n_2)\lambda_m - n \lambda_m^2}{n_2 - (n - n_1)\lambda_m} \tag{2}$$ converges to $\hat \lambda$.  For instance, the sample $(n, n_1, n_2) = (20, 5, 3)$ with the initial choice $\lambda_0 = 1$ yields
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
m & \lambda_m \\
\hline
 0 & 1. \\
 1 & 0.882389 \\
 2 & 0.81657 \\
 3 & 0.777971 \\
 4 & 0.754727 \\
 5 & 0.74051 \\
 6 & 0.731734 \\
 7 & 0.726286 \\
 8 & 0.722891 \\
 9 & 0.720773 \\
 10 & 0.719448 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
 25 & 0.717234 \\
\end{array}$$
Granted, the convergence is rather slow.  We can accelerate the convergence by instead computing the Newton's method recursion for the root of $(1)$:
$$\lambda_{m+1} = \lambda_m + \frac{\left(\left(n_1 - n\right) \lambda_m + n_2\right) \left(n_2 \left(\lambda_m - e^{\lambda_m} + 1\right) - \lambda_m \left(n \lambda_m + \left(n_1 - n\right) e^{\lambda_m} + n - n_1\right)\right)}{-n^2 \lambda_m^2 + 2 n n_2 \lambda_m + n n_1 \lambda_m^2 + e^{\lambda_m} \left(\left(n_1 - n\right) \lambda_m + n_2\right)^2 - n_2^2}. \tag{4}$$
For the same initial choice and sample, we obtain
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
m & \lambda_m \\
\hline
 0 & 1. \\
 1 & 0.785447 \\
 2 & 0.722392 \\
 3 & 0.717264 \\
 4 & 0.717232 \\
 5 & 0.717232
\end{array}$$

You have a univariate function which is bounded in its valid range.

For $\lambda \to 0$ it goes to infinity.
For $\lambda \to \infty$ the function goes to $-n + {n}_{1}$ which is negative.

Show it is monotonic decreasing and then, given the parameters $n, {n}_{1}, {n}_{2}$ the problem is quite easy to solve.

Defining  $n_3=n - n_1 - n_2$, the log-likelihood function can be written as
$$ \ell(\lambda) = -(n_2+n_3)\lambda + n_2 \log \lambda + n_1 \log\left(1 - e^{-\lambda} - \lambda e^{-\lambda}\right). $$
It goes to $-\infty$ as $\lambda \to 0$ or $\lambda \to +\infty$, so  it has a global maximizer in $(0,\infty)$ (it can be shown that $ \ell(\lambda)$ is a concave function.) However, this maximizer cannot be found explicitly. Hence, you cannot find maximum likelihood estimator of $\lambda$, which is a statistic, explicitly. However, for any given values of $n_1,n_2,n_3$ you can find maximum likelihood estimate of $\lambda$, which is an observation of the maximum likelihood estimator, by solving the equation you derived in the OP numerically.
